# PowerShell script running from scheduled task: action failed to start, directory name invalid

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 server running a scheduled task with three actions, each running PowerShell scripts:

[image: actions]

Each of these actions "starts in" the relevant (and correct) directory:

[image: single action]

Originally, the third action - **ApplyABPs** - was set up in exactly the same way as the other two, e.g. a simple "start in" folder and then `.\ApplyABPs.ps1` as the argument. This **worked as intended.**

I wanted to add some logging to the latter script, so I added the following code to dot-source my shared `FunctionsLibrary.ps1` file, create a log file and write to it:

```
# Call functions file...
. (Join-Path "C:\scripts\" FunctionLibrary.ps1)

# Create a log file
$LogFile = Create-Log -Location $LogfileLocation

Write-Log -Important -Text "==== ApplyABPs.ps1 ====="
```

The additions to the `ApplyABPs` script and this `FunctionLibrary.ps1` script work in other files.

If I run this `ApplyABPs.ps1` script from the PowerShell ISE, it works as intended - creates the log file and writes to it.

However, when I then try to run the Scheduled Task, the first two actions run as usual but the third action fails:

[image: task failure]

That code doesn't give me a lot of detail but the `Last Run Result` at the top of Task Scheduler says **`The directory name is invalid. (0x8007010B)`**.

So... for testing purposes, I tried adding the same `FunctionLibrary.ps1` and in-script code amendments to the other two actions. The Task Scheduler then failed immediately and returned the same error for the very first action.

When I then take the code back out, the actions work.

I tried changing the way the Scheduled Task calls PowerShell (hence the `-executionpolicy bypass`, `-noprofile` and `-file` parameters in the top screenshot) but this has made no difference.

Based on the `directory invalid` error message, I'm wondering if PowerShell - when called by the Scheduled Task - is unable to access the dot-sourced file, or something along those lines?

If anyone could shed any light on this specific error, or give an insight into how Task Scheduler calls PowerShell (and the directories/relativity it uses), that would be ideal.

Comment: I always do it with the argument -File "Pathtoscript"
and the rest is as I also always does it
Has never failed me.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following syntax to run a PowerShell script in task scheduler:

**Program/script:** C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

**Add arguments:** -NoLogo -Noninteractive -Noprofile -Command "&{C:\ScriptFolder\get-LicensingInputFromAD.ps1}"

And use the full path\filename for each .ps1 file in your task arguments field.

Comment: Thanks for this SturdyErde. What does `-NoLogo` do?

Comment: -nologo is optional, and I include it out of habit. It simply hides the copyright banner at startup.

Comment: OK. What should my "Start in" folder be? Empty? Or the root directory of the script? (e.g. `c:\scripts\ApplyABPs\`)

Comment: You can leave it empty.

Comment: Thank you. I'll test this when I can and come back to you if it works.

Comment: Avoid `-NoProfile` if your script actually needs things like user-specific environment variables or registry keys.